# how to write a code to get the value of Priority, triage etc which comes under DisplayForm in tfs

Tags: c#, tfs

below is the code how to get the triage and priority values

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
              new Uri("http://abc1.com"));
            WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tpc.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
            WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query("Select [State], [Title]  From WorkItems Where [Work Item Type] = 'Task' AND ([State] <> 'Resolved' AND [State] <> 'Closed') AND [Assigned to] = 'Test' AND [KeywordSearch] Not Contains 'test1'");

foreach (WorkItem queryResult in queryResults )
            {
                int TaskId = queryResult.Id;
                int TaskPriority = queryResult.DisplayForm; // how to get the value of priority
                string TaskTriage = queryResult.DisplayForm;//how to get the value of triage
                string TaskState = queryResult.State;
                DateTime TaskChangedDate = queryResult.ChangedDate;
                string TaskTitle = queryResult.Title;
            }
```

Comment: what are you talking about? down vote!

Comment: it not allowing me to paste the screen shot.

Comment: what I am asking is in TFS the field name Priority and Triage. I have given the code above where I am getting value like "int TaskId = queryResult.Id;" so how to get the values for priority and triage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?  Instead of Field.Name it would probably be better to compare to Field.ReferenceName but I don't know the reference name for your Priority and TaskTriage fields.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
    new Uri("http://server/tfs"));
var workItemStore =  tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>(); 
WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(
    "Select [State], [Title]  From WorkItems " + 
    " Where [Work Item Type] = 'Task' AND " + 
    " ([State] <> 'Resolved' AND [State] <> 'Closed') ");

foreach (WorkItem queryResult in queryResults)
{
    int TaskId = queryResult.Id;

    //int TaskPriority = queryResult.DisplayForm; // how to get the value of priority
    //string TaskTriage = queryResult.DisplayForm;//how to get the value of triage
    foreach (Field n in queryResult.Fields)
    {
        if (n.Name == "TaskPriority")
        {
            int TaskPriority = (int)n.Value; 
        }
        else if (n.Name == "TaskTriage")
        {
            string TaskTriage = (n.Value ?? string.Empty ).ToString(); 
        }
     }

     string TaskState = queryResult.State;
     DateTime TaskChangedDate = queryResult.ChangedDate;
     string TaskTitle = queryResult.Title;
}
```

Comment: this program is working but not able to extracting the values of Priority and Triage because it is not under "queryResult.Fields" it is under DisplayForm. when I changed it to DisplayForm it is giving error: no extension method DisplayForm accepting a first argument of type.

Comment: foreach ( Field n in rdTaskResult.DisplayForm) the error is cannot convert type char to Microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.Client.field

Comment: The DisplayForm field contains XML that defines the user interface to display for that item.  It does not contain any data, just a user interface definition.  Are you trying to extract the value assigned to TaskPriority and TaskTriage, or the user interface to display for those fields?

Comment: i need the values of Priority and Triage and not able to get it. so can some one please help me how to get the values of these fields.

Comment: Try looking in the Fields collection for a Field with the ReferenceName equal to 'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority' or 'Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Triage'